# AttributeError: 'MyTopo' object has no attribute 'addlink'

Tags: python, mininet

### Heading

I got the error ( attributeerror. 'MyTopo' object has no attribute 'addlink' ) when I tried running the "Fat-tree topology.py" script in mininet .Please help.

Comment: Do you want us to imagine whats there in topology.py and answer you? Right?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to be sure you imported the `mininet` library.

The fuction you need is called `addLink`, not `addlink`, which caused your error.